# How might one prove two functions asymptotic?

Tags: soft-question, asymptotics

Lets say that function $f$ and $g$ look to be converging on one another. What tests might you use to prove that they are/are not asymptotic?

If you want an example to work on, lets say $f(x)=\ln x$ and $g(x)=x-x^{1-1/x}$

I know that these functions are asymptotic, but have no way of proving it. Thanks to all help in advance.

Comment: There are several similar ideas; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for a survey.

Comment: One such way is to show that the ratio of those two functions goes to 1 as x goes to infinity. Or that their difference goes to zero as x goes to infinity.

Comment: @DaveNine: Those are very different notions if both functions have limits of $0$ or $\infty$, e.g. $1/x$ and $\exp(-x)$, or $x^2+x$ and $x^2$

Comment: What does $x$ approach? 0, $\infty$, 1, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$,

$\begin{align*}
x^{1-1/x}
&=e^{\ln x(1-1/x)}\\
&=e^{\ln x}e^{-\ln x/x}\\
&=x(1-\ln x/x + (\ln x)^2/(2 x^2)+o(1/x^2))\\
&=x-\ln x+ (\ln x)^2/(2 x)+o(1/x)\\
\end{align*}
$

so

$\begin{align*}
g(x)
&=x-x^{1-1/x}\\
&=x-(x-\ln x+ (\ln x)^2/(2 x)+o(1/x))\\
&=\ln x- (\ln x)^2/(2 x)+o(1/x)\\
&\approx \ln x\\
\end{align*}
$

I believe that
this is what you want.